# Explain race condition in double checked locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition, double-checked-locking

```
void undefined_behaviour_with_double_checked_locking()
{
    if(!resource_ptr)                                    #1
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(resource_mutex);  #2
        if(!resource_ptr)                                #3
        {
           resource_ptr.reset(new some_resource);        #4
        }
    }
    resource_ptr->do_something();                        #5
}
```

> if a thread sees the pointer written by another thread, it might not
>   see the newly-created instance of some_resource, resulting in the call
>   to do_something() operating on incorrect values. This is an example of
>   the type of race condition defined as a data race by the C++ Standard,
>   and thus specified as undefined behaviour.

**Question**> I have seen the above explanation for why the code has the double checked locking problem that causes the race condition. However, I still have difficulties to understand what the problem is. Maybe a concrete two-threads step-by-step workflow can help me really understand the race problem for the above the code.

One of the solution mentioned by the book is as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<some_resource> resource_ptr;
std::once_flag resource_flag;

void init_resource()
{
    resource_ptr.reset(new some_resource);
}
void foo()
{
    std::call_once(resource_flag,init_resource); #1
    resource_ptr->do_something();
}
#1 This initialization is called exactly once
```

Any comment is welcome
-Thank you

Comment: Read the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/367690/14065) for some non obvious problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest problem scenario is in the case where the intialization of `some_resource` doesn't depend on `resource_ptr`. In that case, the compiler is free to assign a value to `resource_ptr` before it fully constructs `some_resource`.

For example, if you think of the operation of `new some_resource` as consisting of two steps:

- allocate the memory for `some_resource`
- initialize `some_resource` (for this discussion, I'm going to make the simplifying assumption that this initialization can't throw an exception)

Then you can see that the compiler could implement the mutex-protected section of code as:

```
1. allocate memory for `some_resource`
2. store the pointer to the allocated memory in `resource_ptr`
3. initialize `some_resource`
```

Now it becomes clear that if another thread executes the function between steps 2 and 3, then `resource_ptr->do_something()` could be called while `some_resource` has not been initialized.

Note that it's also possible on some processor architectures for this kind of reordering to occur in hardware unless the proper memory barriers are in place (and such barriers would be implemented by the mutex).

Comment: For "new someresource; ",  this is guaranteed by C++ operator new that the resource is  initialized before return.  This is how operator new always work in C++, right ?  How come the step 1/3 separated? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

In this case (depending on the implementation of `.reset` and `!`) there may be a problem when Thread 1 gets part-way through initializing `resource_ptr` and then gets paused/switched. Thread 2 then comes along, performs the first check, sees that the pointer is not null, and skips the lock/fully-initialized check. It then uses the partially-initialized object (probably resulting in bad things happening). Thread 1 then comes back and finishes initializing, but it's too late.

The reason that a partially-initialized `resource_ptr` is possible is because the CPU is allowed to reorder instructions (as long as it doesn't change single-thread behaviour). So, while the code looks like it should fully-initialize the object and then assign it to `resource_ptr`, the optimized assembly code might be doing something quite different, and the CPU is also not guaranteed to run the assembly instructions in the order they are specified in the binary!

The takeaway is that when multiple threads are involved, memory fences (locks) are the only way guarantee that things happen in the right order.

Comment: So your key point is that the race problem can happen if the `.reset` is half-baked and paused. In other word, if `.reset` is NOT an atomic operation, then the problem will happen.

Comment: Yes, the interaction of reset and the ! operator are the essential point. If you look at the implementation of these methods, remember also that the compiler may reorder some statements for you (a common cause of double-checked locking woes).

Comment: How is a partially initialized object possible ? new some_resource is atomic since C++ operator new is guaranteed to first allocate and then initialize the object before return it to caller.    Are you saying the the .reset implementation may split these 2 steps?

Comment: @FaceBro it is only partially initialized for a short amount of time, and before thread 1's constructor returns. However, thread 1 may still be running the constructor (initializing the object) when thread 2 tries to use the object (as the heap allocation mutex has ended but the object initialization is still in progress). C++ operator new is not atomic -- that's what this whole question is about.