# multi-thread program initialization using call_once vs atomic_flag

Tags: c++, multithreading

In book *C++ Concurrency in Action 2nd, 3.3.1*, the author introduced a way using `call_once` function to avoid double-checked locking pattern when doing initialization in multi-thread program,

```
std::shared_ptr<some_resource> resource_ptr;
std::once_flag resource_flag;

void init_resource()
{
    resource_ptr.reset(new some_resource);
}
void foo()
{
    std::call_once(resource_flag,init_resource); #1
    resource_ptr->do_something();
}
```

the reason is explained in this [answer][1]. I used to use `atomic_flag` to do initialization in multi-thread program, something like this:

```
td::atomic_flag init = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
std::atomic<bool> initialized = false;
void Init()
{
if (init.test_and_set()) return;
  DoInit();
  initialized = true;
}
void Foo(){
  if(!initialized) return;
   DoSomething(); // use some variable intialized in DoInit()
}
```

every threads will call `Init()` before call `Foo()`.

After read the book, I wonder will the above pattern cause race condition, therefore not safe to use? Is it possible that the compiler reorder the instructions and `initialized` become true before `DoInit()` finish?
[1]: [Explain race condition in double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570903/explain-race-condition-in-double-checked-locking)

Comment: "Every thread will call `Init()` before `Foo()`: except for the one that doesn't. This is a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The race condition in your code happens when thread 1 enters `DoInit` and thread 2 skips it and proceeds to `Foo`.

You handle it with `if(!initialized) return` in `Foo` but this is not always possible: you should always expect a method to accidently do nothing and you can forget to add such checks to other methods.

With `std::call_once` with concurrent invocation the execution will only continue after the action is executed.

Regarding reordering, atomics operations use [memory_order_seq_cst](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering) by default that does not allow any reordering.

Comment: so if I add initialized check at the beginning of other functions , this approach has the same effect as the one using call_once and once_flag right?

Comment: and I'm kind of confused that why it is not always possible to add initialized check

Comment: @zenxy no the approach you try to use is not good. It may happen that `x.Init(); x.Foo();` will not really run `Foo();` because `initialized` is still false as another thread is in the process of finishing the initialization.

Comment: @ALX23z yes, currently when I use this approach, if other thread is call Foo() before Init() is finished, Foo will simply print error message and return. If one thread is in the process of call_once and the other thread come, will the later thread wait call_once finish?

Comment: @codesavesworld -- yes, the second thread will block until `call_once` finishes. That's the point!